# How docker treats fsync on guest filesystem? Is it possible to lost data during host system crash?

Tags: docker, journal, fsync

Consider the following scenario:

- We work with DBMS inside docker container;
- DBMS writes WAL or REDO log, and calls fsync on transaction commits;
- fsync instructs guest OS to flush 'dirty' IO buffers to disk;
- Data stays in IO buffer on host OS;
- Host system crashes;

Is it possible scenario?

Comment: With docker you have only one linux kernel - it's both host and guest.

Comment: @Roman, thanks for the answer. Can you provide some links explaining this? I just can't understand how, for instance, debian container can run on CentOS, having the same kernel.

Comment: All these questions are for [unix.se].

Comment: @Roman I'm well aware of how it works in Linux kernel, my question is precisely about Docker.